# Iterating over heterogeneous container

Tags: java, generics

I am using a heterogeneous container similar to [this one](https://github.com/marhan/effective-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/effectivejava/examples/chapter05/item29/Favorites.java). I can put and receive objects from the container with ease:

```
Favorites f = new Favorites();
f.putFavorite(String.class, "Java");
String someString = f.getFavorite(String.class);
```

But there seem to be no easy way to iterate over such container. I can add a `keySet()` method to the `Favorites` class and simply return the key set of the internal `Map` object:

```
public Set<Class<?>> keySet() {
  return favorites.keySet();
}
```

Now, I would like to iterate over the keys, use the keys to get the associated values, and call some methods on the received objects:

```
for (Class<?> klass : f.keySet()) {
   // f.getFavorite(klass).<SOME_METHOD_SPECIFIC_TO_THE_CLASS-KEY>
}
```

I thought that I could access the methods of the objects held in my container by calling `klass.cast(f.getFavorite(klass)).SOME_METHOD()`, but it doesn't work either (meaning, I cannot access any methods except for the `Object`-related methods).

Let's say, that in my use case I would like to inspect the interfaces of all these objects I iterate over and act accordingly to the detected interface. Let's also assume that I may have dozens of objects of various classes and all of them implement one of three interfaces.

The only solution I can think of is to stuff my code with dozens of `isinstance` checks, but I would prefer a less cumbersome approach (i.e. checking if a given object implements one of three interfaces).

Comment: Do you have an idea of the "less cumbersome approach" you're envisioning?  I mean if you have three different pieces of code you want to run depending on whether it implements one of three different interfaces, it seems like whatever approach we can suggest will have to have three different branches.  So it'd be good to have clarity on what precisely you're finding cumbersome.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I consider the "checking if a given object implements one of three interfaces" approach to be less cumbersome. At least when compared to the scenario with dozens of "if" statements.

Comment: I'm not sure where we're going from 3 if statements to dozens...my answer would use 3 if statements, is that what you're looking for?  The issue with checking three interfaces at once is that you're going then need to do something different depending on which of the three interface it matched anyway, so what does it gain you?

Comment: I think my question boils down to this: in the foreach loop from my initial question, when I receive an object with `f.getFavorite(klass)`, can I use reflection to list methods of the returned instance? I know that the object is of class `klass` so I think I should be able to list its methods.

Comment: You can certainly use reflection (ick), but what is reflection going to get you over the type safe way I listed though?  At the end of the day, *your code needs to know what method to call*.  If it's the same method signature, the standard way to do that is to have all of the classes implement an interface and then call using static linking as in my answer.  The only reason you would want to bring reflection into this is if the method you were trying to call was itself dynamic (i.e. you don't actually *know* what method you're trying to call until runtime).

Comment: I see your point, and I think your solution is as good as it can get. I am porting a piece of code from Python and I sometimes get to the point when I have to stop thinking Python and redesign the original approach instead. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes.  Java (as a language) does not have any usable support for [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python).  Java's primary mechanism for contract-based invocation is through interface inheritance.  Although it recently gained support for [`invokedynamic`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/scripting-jvm-languages/invokedynamic-101.html) at the VM level, this is mostly for other JVM languages and not Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By trying to call a specific method on each entry, you are basically saying that you know better than the compiler, and that you know each entry has a specific super class.

If you know that's the case, you can use `Class#asSubclass` to type `klass` as `Class<? extends KnownSuper>` so that `getFavorite` will then return a subclass of `KnownSuper` (and therefore expose the method):

```
Class<KnownSuper> superClass = KnownSuper.class; //class with callMethod()
for (Class<?> klass : f.keySet()) {
    f.getFavorite(klass.asSubClass(superClass)).callMethod()
}
```

However, this will obviously give a runtime exception if one of the key classes does not extend `KnownSuper`.  So if the above would be safe, you should parameterize your heterogeneous container to only accept key classes that extend from `KnownSuper` in the first place.

If not all entries *will* be of this type, you could also check first if the key is suitable when iterating:

```
Class<KnownSuper> superClass = KnownSuper.class; //class with callMethod()
for (Class<?> klass : f.keySet()) {
    if (superClass.isAssignableFrom(klass)) {
        f.getFavorite(klass.asSubClass(superClass)).callMethod()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this simple example

**Say you have below Favorites  class definition**

```
public class Favorites  extends HashMap<String, String> {

}
```

**Here is the test class**

```
public class TestGeneric {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Favorites  f = new Favorites();
        f.put("test", "test");

        for (String test1 : f.keySet()) {

             f.get("").charAt(index)// you will see all string specific  method as compiler knows in advance what object map going to contain


    }

}
```

The moment you change `Favorites  extends HashMap<String, String>` to `Favorites  extends HashMap` you will just object specific methods as compiler does not know in advance which object Favorites is going to put in map

Comment: The point of using **heterogenous** container is to be able to put **heterogeneous** objects into it. For example: `f.putFavorite(String.class, "Java"); f.putFavorite(Integer.class, 1);`.